# Java accessing private property via Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have following package structure and classes.

```
package  X 
    Class A
        private string fieldX;
        protected string getFieldX(){ return fieldX};

package Y
    Class B extends A
    Class C extends B
```

I have the ClassC object and trying to get fieldX via reflection.

```
Class partypes[] = new Class[0];
Object arglist[] = new Object[0];
Method getContextMethod = ClassC.class.getMethod("getFieldX",partypes);
String retValue =  (string) getContextMethod.invoke(classCInstance, arglist);
```

But I am getting NoSuchMethod exception.

I tried also reach the fieldX directly. But this time I am getting NoSuchField Exception.

```
Field reqField = ClassC.class.getDeclaredField("fieldX");
reqField.setAccessible(true);
Object value = reqField.get(classCInstance);
String retValue =  (string) value;
```

What is the thing I am doing wrong?
Is there a way to get this fieldX from ClassC object?

***Solution: (thanks a lot vz0 for solution);***

***Direct access to private field:***

```
Field reqField = ClassA.class.getDeclaredField("fieldX");
reqField.setAccessible(true);
String value = (String)reqField.get(clazzc);
```

***Method Call;***

```
Class partypes[] = new Class[0];
Object arglist[] = new Object[0];
Method getContextMethod = ClassA.class.getDeclaredMethod("getFieldX",partypes);
getContextMethod.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println((String)getContextMethod.invoke(clazzc, arglist));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Class.getMethod` call is for public methods only. You need to use the `Class.getDeclaredMethod` call and then setting the `Method.setAccessible` property to true:

```
Class partypes[] = new Class[0];
Object arglist[] = new Object[0];
Method getContextMethod = ClassA.class.getDeclaredMethod("getFieldX",partypes);

getContextMethod.setAccessible(true);

String retValue =  (string) getContextMethod.invoke(classCInstance, arglist);
```

**EDIT:** Since the `getFieldX` method is declared on `ClassA`, you need to fetch the Method from ClassA and not ClassC. As opposite to `getMethod` call, the `getDeclaredMethod` call [ignores superclasses](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class[]%29).

Comment: thanks vz0 for your answer. This is working. Added direct access to private field to answer also.